# JMeter | Request with Patch Method giving error-"Invalid HTTP method: PATCH"

Tags: java, jmeter, patch

I am getting the below error when I am trying to hit a request having **Method: PATCH**

Using **JMeter Version:-apache-jmeter-5.4.1**

> "java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH   at
> java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:487)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:596)"
> [image]

It will be helpful if I get expert assistance to resolve their issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change "Client Implementation" to `HttpClient4` either at "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler or in the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-http-request#Best%20Practices) - this way the change will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers in the HTTP Request Defaults [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are [diffrent HTTPSampler implementations](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/b73f69074f8b3b5d71767ab0fedb52f16a1e55d6/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerFactory.java#L86) the Java one uses HttpURLConnection [here](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/b73f69074f8b3b5d71767ab0fedb52f16a1e55d6/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPJavaImpl.java#L193). As you can see in this bug ticket [it does not support PATCH](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7016595)
In `user.properties`

```
HTTPSampler.implementation: HttpClient4
```

or in jmx using

```
<stringProp name="HTTPSampler.implementation">HttpClient4</stringProp>
```